# "Exception: Scanner closed" how to re-open it within (while.. loop)

Tags: java

I am new to coding and trying to learn JAVA and with different approaches for simple tasks.
I want to make a simple address Book with functions like "Add contact, search by number, search by name etc." Most of my methods work but I have a problem with the following two.

When I call `modify Contact` even if I tried to replace the name ,the code creates a new line in the file. So then I call `delete By Name` to delete the unmodified line, and I am getting the following error.(I know the cause of the error but I cannot find a solution that works....)

```
    public static void modifyContact(String namee){
        Scanner sca =new Scanner(System.in);
        String newName = sca.nextLine();
        try  {
            String[] s;
            boolean foundPerson = false;
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("addressBook.txt"));
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                s = sc.nextLine().split(",");
                if (s[0].equals(namee)) {
                    s[0]=s[0].replace(s[0],newName);
                    System.out.println("Name is " + namee + " phone number is " + s[1] + " ,address is " + s[3] + " and email is " + s[2]);
                    foundPerson = true;


                    deleteByName(namee);
                File file =new File("addressBook.txt");
                FileWriter pw = new FileWriter(file,true);
                pw.write(s[0]+","+s[1]+","+s[2]+","+s[3]);

                pw.close();

                }
            }
            sc.close();
            deleteByName(namee);

            if (!foundPerson) {
                System.out.println("No contact found with " + namee);
                }
            } 
            catch (IOException ex) {
           //System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
    }
```

```
    public static void deleteByName(String na){
        try{
            File inputFile = new File("addressBook.txt");   // Your file
            File tempFile = new File("TempFile.txt");// temp file

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));
        String currentLine;

        while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if(currentLine.contains(na))
                   continue;

            writer.write(currentLine);
            writer.newLine();
        }

        writer.close();
        reader.close();
        boolean del=inputFile.delete();
        boolean successful = tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
        System.out.println(del);
        System.out.println(successful);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.ensureOpen(Scanner.java:1150)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.findWithinHorizon(Scanner.java:1781)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.hasNextLine(Scanner.java:1610)
    at com.christos.hw.Main.modifyContact(Main.java:170)
    at com.christos.hw.Main.displayMenu(Main.java:268)
    at com.christos.hw.Main.selectAgain(Main.java:96)
    at com.christos.hw.Main.displayMenu(Main.java:231)
    at com.christos.hw.Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

Comment: You are closing the `Scanner` within the `while` loop. That won't work of course. By the way, your indentation is confusing, that may be the source of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solutions:

- Don't close the scanner. Keep it open until you don't need it. In other words, close it **after** the loop.
- Recreate the scanner by calling `sc = new Scanner(new File("addressBook.txt"));`. However, since this will create a new scanner, it'll start reading from the first line again.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `sc.close();` after the while loop, not inside it. With your logic, the scanner is unusable from second iteration of the loop itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you call `deleteByName()` where you remove original file inside the loop and then reuse `Scanner`.

You should do it like this:

1. Find all `name`
2. Call `deleteByName()` with all found `names`.

---

```
public final class AddressBookManager {

    private final File file;

    public AddressBookManager(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public void modifyContact(String oldName, String newName) throws IOException {
        if (isContactExists(oldName))
            updateContactName(oldName, newName);
    }

    private boolean isContactExists(String name) throws FileNotFoundException {
        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(file)) {
            while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
                String str = scan.nextLine();

                if (str.startsWith(name + ',')) {
                    String[] parts = str.split(",");
                    System.out.format("Contact found. Name '%s', phone number '%s', address '%s', email '%s'\n", parts[0], parts[1], parts[2],
                            parts[3]);
                    return true;
                }
            }

            System.out.println("No contact found with name '" + name + '\'');
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void updateContactName(String curName, String newName) throws IOException {
        File tmp = new File(file.getParent(), "TempFile.txt");

        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
             BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tmp))) {
            String str;

            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                if (str.startsWith(curName))
                    str = newName + str.substring(str.indexOf(','));

                out.write(str);
                out.newLine();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("remove old file: " + file.delete());
        System.out.println("rename temp file: " + tmp.renameTo(file));
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        AddressBookManager addressBookManager = new AddressBookManager(new File("d:/addressBook.txt"));

        String curName = "oleg";
        String newName = getNewName(curName);
        addressBookManager.modifyContact(curName, newName);
    }

    private static String getNewName(String curName) {
        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.print("Enter new name for (" + curName + "): ");
            return scan.nextLine();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Even if I fixed the problem, i will try that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when  you close a scanner with system.in the input stream from system is also closed. so you will not be able to reuse the scanner even if you create a new scanner with System.in .If you are using java 7 you can use try with resources to close all the autocCleasable resources by Java itself. This will resolve the issue.

```
    public static void modifyContact(String namee) {

        File file = new File("addressBook.txt");        
        try (Scanner sca = new Scanner(System.in);
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(file); 
            FileWriter pw = new FileWriter(file, true);) {
            String[] s;
            boolean foundPerson = false;
            String newName = sca.nextLine();
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                s = sc.nextLine().split(",");
                if (s[0].equals(namee)) {
                    s[0] = s[0].replace(s[0], newName);
                    System.out.println("Name is " + namee + " phone number is " + s[1] + " ,address is " + s[3]
                            + " and email is " + s[2]);
                    foundPerson = true;
                    deleteByName(namee);
                    pw.write(s[0] + "," + s[1] + "," + s[2] + "," + s[3]);
                }
            }
            if (!foundPerson) {
                System.out.println("No contact found with " + namee);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I added after the loop

```
sc.close();
deleteByName(namee);
```

and it seems to works fine.
Thank you all for the help.